# How do I jump to a UIViewController in a storyboard and still retain the navigation hierarchy?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, storyboard, xcode-storyboard

I'm working on a storyboard-based project for ios5, and it is working well so far, but I want to save the user's state when they exit so that when they return to the app, I can jump them back to the place in the storyboard where they were when they left.

My understanding is that as you navigate through a storyboard, it creates a stack of UIViewControllers, so that when you dismiss the current controller, it knows which one to display.  But if I jump to one of the UIViewControllers in a storyboard programmatically when the app starts up, it would not have that history, that stack of controllers, to backtrack along.  If nothing else, if two controllers segue into the same controller at some point in the storyboard, it wouldn't know which to go back to.

What is the proper way of dealing with this?  Do I just go through the storyboard to the point where the user left off, presenting each UIViewController with animations set to NO until I get to the one that the user was on?  (And if so, what's the best way to store that information?  Are there any methods/classes that can assist with this, or am I rolling my own way of storing their through the storyboard?)

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything. With ios5 the program will just go to the background when the user leaves the app and it will return to where they left off when select your app again. Is there more to the problem than that?

Comment: Relying on that to restore state isn't sufficient, correct?  If the user reboots the device that state is lost, for instance.

Comment: Typically a user reboots to reset everything including your app. Unless a user would lose data you don't need to save your app state. If there is a potential data loss you need to save the data anyway by detecting if the app is being put in the background and saving it then.

Answer (score 0):

One option is using [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You can't exactly save the exact instances of `UIViewControllers` on the disk, and retrieve them as if they were in the memory. What happens is that, you should somehow, e.g. key/value, identify each of your viewControllers that you are interested and want to save their state. Also you need to key each element you want to save its state, and then save using `NSUserDefaults`.

For exmaple, let's say you have a hierarchy like this:

HomeView > ListOfNotes > NoteAtIndexPath:x

And the user is viewing NoteAtIndexPath:x, and also let's assume the font size is dynamic, so user can make it bigger or smaller at the time of viewing. You can define two keys: `IndexOfLastNoteViewed` and `LasFontSizeViewed`, and save them:

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUser] setInteger:5 forKey:IndexOfLastNoteViewed];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUser] setFloat:17.0 forKey:LasFontSizeViewed];
```

When the application launches again, you can check the keys, and browse programmatically to HomeView > ListOfNotes > NoteAtIndexPath:5.

Here are some links that might help you:

- [Application states](http://koduco.com/2010/11/01/ios-application-states/)
- [App States and Multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)
- [Beginning IPhone Development: Exploring the IPhone SDK By Dave Mark, Jeff LaMarche
  -- Application Settings and User Defaults](http://books.google.com/books?id=WV9glgdrrrUC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA303#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Right - it's not the saving state of the individual UIViewControllers' data that I'm concerned about.  It's how I start up directly on the correct UIViewController at app startup so that the hierarchy remains intact?

Comment: If you are looking at it from the code perspective, the hierarchy is intact anyway. Your point is how to restore the last state user was viewing. And the answer is you need to record those settings that can be changed by the user, and set the variables to them again when you are back to the app. The hierarchy can not be changed by the user. It's embedded in your design. Although from the user perspective, he is jumping from one view to another, you know programmatically how he's got there. By saving that in NSUserDefaults, you create a landmark to return to.